# Flank Steak Sous Vide - Blood Spots?

Tags: steak, sous-vide, reheating

I got a SV wand for X-Mas, so have been doing alot of that this month.

I did a flank steak today, which I cut into 3 parts, 3 bags, and did at 52 Deg C for 4 hours.  I then Ice Bath'd all three pieces, and 2 went in the freezer, and one went in the fridge.

For dinner, I pulled the fridge version, and warmed up at 48 Deg C for 30 minutes while preparing Lomo Saltado fixins.

When I was slicing the steak, against the muscle grain, I ran into 2 or 3 small blood spots (bright red pockets in the meat - maybe 1" across and spread across 1" worth of slices.  I took them out, but was wondering if anyone knows what they are, and what that means?  I've cooked many steaks in my 30+ yeas on this earth, and had never seen that.

Second, follow on question: if I want the other 2 steaks more well done, can I pull from the freezer 90 minutes before another meal, and SV at 54 Deg C, or does "twice cooking" them introduce new problems?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would think the red pockets are liquefied fat and/or water with red dye in them (and some myoglobin, which is what makes red meat red, but often dye is the bigger reason).

If it's steak from a supermarket, it's probably thoroughly dyed, so maybe some of the dye (or a lot of it!) stuck with the fat.  Blood wouldn't be bright red, it would be oxidized and a nice brown/gray (if it were even in the steak - almost no blood remains in a steak, it's not why they're red).  If you're used to grilling or similar methods, those would allow the fat (and water) to drip off, while SV won't: you're packing it in a bag and keeping the water and fat inside (that being the point of sous-vide cooking, after all).

Comment: Thanks @Joe M.  This makes sense to me.  I usually get my steak from a butcher in the area (San Francisco: Guerra Quality Meats), but there was a sale at Andronico's, so I got the flank steak there.  Would the existence of this red spot indicate a quality issue with the meat - or just part of what you get with SV that you don't get with Grilling?  Any way to avoid for the future?  THANKS!

Comment: I'm not a SV expert, so I'm not sure - but I think it's not significant.

Answer (score 0):

Flank steak consists of the abdominal muscles, primarily the [rectus abdominis](http://www.ams.usda.gov/AMSv1.0/getfile?dDocName=STELDEV3003281) muscle.  The [superior epigastric artery and vein](http://www.wjes.org/content/5/1/12/figure/F4?highres=y)* pass through the muscle.  Sometimes, during processing, small clots will form inside the blood vessels which will manifest as blood spots when the muscle is cut perpendicular to grain.

*The drawing linked is of a human, but in this case bovine anatomy is similar.

Comment: Thank Didgeridrew!  What's weird is that I have never seen that before when grilling a Flank Steak.  I guess the SV prep left the juice in while grilling lets it out!